# Identify this 2-pin, grid-style, wire-terminated connector?

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone help identify the type of connector in the picture below?
I need to make an extension cord for an electric bicycle's control throttle which happens to have that connector on it.

[image]

Comment: Looks Molex-y...

Comment: Possibly a JST connector? Photo is fuzzy.

Comment: Do you have any more information to share?  Brand name of product you need to extend, distance pins to pin or something to give us scale, any markings on the units, better pics, etc?

Comment: Can you add a better picture?

Comment: this was the result of google image search!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a 2 pin JST SM type connector. Look on page 3, top right. http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/JSTSM.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [this](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Hirose-Connector/HNC2-25S-2/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtsLRyDR9nM12QO1/vCmZ6X5IG1y2sO41A=)?

I looked around on mouser's website and tried to find your connector - but you'd probably be more successful.  I had to make some guesses on things like pitch in order to get results that were even remotely similar to your connector.  Their parametric searching tool is really useful though, for situations like this.  I found a lot of "almost right" type of connectors that might actually solve your problem, but it's hard to make out in your image what some of the details are.

I'd recommend starting [here](http://www.mouser.com/Interconnects/Rectangular-Connectors/) and adding your parameters

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a Molex KK to me, like PC fan connectors.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector

Comment: It definitely isn't -- KK (or any other Molex connector) doesn't have spring plastic on the sides.